# How to split data into two parts of specified ratio NOT randomly

Tags: r

If I had a data frame with 100 rows, and I wanted to split the data into test and train data with a split ratio of 0.7, how would I split that but not randomly? For example, I want the first 70% to be one chunk and the last 30% to be another chunk. 
Chunk 1:

```
row     example
1       a
2       b
.
.
.
68      a3
69      a4
70      a5
```

Chunk 2:

```
row     example
71       a6
72       a7
.
.
.
98      b1
99      b2
100     b3
```

I wouldnt want random rows in each split

Comment: `train=df[1:70,], test=df[71:100,]`

Comment: @user2974951 This wouldn't work for a dataset that has anything other tan 100 rows. I am not looking to hard code the values either

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
split(mtcars, 1:nrow(mtcars)/nrow(mtcars) >= 0.7)
```

Resulting in 22 and 10 rows, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option, using `split` + `findInterval`

```
res <- split(df,findInterval(seq(nrow(df)),round(nrow(df)*0.7),rightmost.closed = T))
```